# Count number of rows in Mysql using PHP7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have upgraded PHP on my server from version 5 to 7 and I found out that `mysql_*` functions were removed and now I should use mysqli or PDO. I updated the following code (mysqli instead of mysql) that I used to print number of rows in a given table, but it doesn't work as it used to.

```
$link = mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
mysql_select_db("xxx", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blackandwhite", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n"; // This works in PHP5
```

Updated code PHP7:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
mysqli_select_db("xxx", $link);

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM blackandwhite", $link);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n"; // This doesnt work anymore.
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php and check order of parameters

Comment: Converting `mysql_` to `msqli_` is not a straight forward one to one change

Comment: If you're having to do a migration anyway, I would recommend using PDO rather than the mysqli library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mysqli_` functions actually accept the link as the first argument, as it is non-optional like it is with the normal `mysql_` functions.

This should work as you expect:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password","db_name");
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8mb4");

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) FROM blackandwhite");
$num_rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
```

Comment: Edit discussed in meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396454/is-this-question-edit-ok